# Upload Profile Image to Parse?

Tags: javascript, curl, parse-platform

I'm trying to use code in my website app (so it can be coded in HTML, JavaScript, CSS, etc.) into upload a user's image to Parse. I know that it has to do with this https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#files-associating-with-objects, but I can't figure it out.

Also, kind of a related question, but it gives one of the programming options as "cURL". Is JavaScript able to code in cURL?

Thanks.

Comment: you are pretty far off on this. Why are you looking at the rest API docs? Have you written any code yet? Dont you want to use the javascript sdk?

Comment: I've done a lot of stuff using Parse and I figured this would work just as well... I've also written a lot of code, so I'm not sure what you're trying to ask... Are you suggesting that there's an easier alternative?

Comment: I googled it: https://www.parse.com/questions/uploading-files-to-parse-using-javascript-and-the-rest-api You can also just use the javascript sdk https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide

Comment: Oh, I see. I am currently using the JavaScript SDK for Parse for other things. I'll look up that article and let you know if it worked. Thanks @ChrisL

Comment: Yeah, feel free to contact me if you need help!

Comment: It works, thanks! The only thing I'm stumped on now, though, is that it appears JavaScript won't let the website access the file from Parse.com because it is an external site... Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You should do a query for the file and get the url

Comment: Never mind, it was a simple error on my part. Thanks so much for the help!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris answered this, but he didn't post it under an answer, so I figured that I would. Thanks for your help, Chris! ;)

**Answer:**

I googled it: https://www.parse.com/questions/uploading-files-to-parse-using-javascript-and-the-rest-api. You can also just use the JavaScript SDK found [here](http://parse.com/docs/js/guide).